# When to try and tune the SQL or just summarize data in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `EMPLOYEE` table in a SQL Server 2008 database which stores information for employees (~80,000+) many times for each year.  For instance, there could by 10 different instances of each employees data for different years.

I'm reporting on this data via a web app, and wanted to report mostly with queries directly against the `EMPLOYEE` table, using functions to get information that needed to be computed or derived for reporting purposes.

These functions sometimes have to refer to an `EMPLOYEE_DETAIL` table which has 100,000+ rows for each year - so now that I'm starting to write some reporting-type queries, some take around 5-10 seconds to run, which is a bit too slow.

My question is, in a situation like this, should I try and **tune functions and such so I

can always query the data directly for reporting (real-time)**, or is a better approach to **summarize the data I need in a static table** via a procedure or saved query, and use that for any reporting?

I guess any changes in reporting needs could be reflected in the "summarizing mechanism" I use...but I'm torn on what to do here...

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses.  The slowness currently seems to come from one function I have that sums up values for each employee. I'll try indexing on the source table (the DETAIL I mentioned) for the columns I use in that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before refactoring your functions I would suggest you take a look at your indexes. You would be amazed at how much of a difference well constructed indexes can make. Also, index maintenance will probably require less effort than a "summarizing mechanism"

Comment: I added indexes on all columns that my specific sum function uses, and it is still super slow when doing it real-time in queries.  I think I'm going to use the functions at time of inserting this reporting data, and then I at least can keep my standard functions, and then point to this pre-calculated value to avoid any performance issues.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use the following approach:

- If it's possible to tune the function, for example, by adding an index specifically suited to the needs of your query or by using a different clustered index on your tables, then tune it. Life is so much easier if you do not have to deal with redundancy.
- If you feel that you have reached the point where optimization is no longer possible (fetching a few thousand fragmented pages from disk *will* take some time, no matter what you do), it might be better to store some data redundantly rather than completely restructuring the way you store your data. If you take this route, be very careful to avoid inconsistencies.

  SQL Server, for example, allows you to use [indexed views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx), which store summary data (i.e. the result of some view) redundantly for quick access, but also automatically take care of updating that data. Of course, there is a performance penalty when modifying the underlying tables, so you'll have to check if that fits your needs.

  Ohterwise, if the data does not have to be up-to-date, periodic recalculation of the summaries (at night, when nobody is working) might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I try and tune functions and
>   such so I can always query the data
>   directly for reporting (real-time), or
>   is a better approach to summarize the
>   data I need in a static table via a
>   procedure or saved query, and use that
>   for any reporting?

From the description of your data and queries (historic data for up to 10 years, aggregate queries for computed values) this looks like an OLAP business inteligence type data store, whre the is more important to look at historic trends and old read-only data rather than see the current churn and last to the second update that occured. As such the best solution would be to setup an SQL Analysis Services server and query that instead of the relational database.

This is a generic response, without knowing the details of your specifics. Your data size (~80k-800k employee records, ~100k -1 mil detail records) is well within the capabilities of SQL Server relational engine to give sub second responses on aggregates and business inteligence type queries, specially if you add in something like indexed views for some problem aggregates. But what the relational engine (SQL Server) can do will pale in comparison with what the analytical engine (SQL Server Analysis Services) can.

Comment: I agree with that completely, and there is OLAP at my organization (Cognos 7)...but there is no API in that version so I can't query those cubes or data.  Just trying to implement a simple "reporting-lite" for the web.

Comment: The the question you ask can e rephrased as "Should I use an of-the-shelf OLAP engine or should I roll my own?". You know that the answer, on the long run, will always be "use one of-the-shelf". I know in large orgs there is always more at stake (oh, the politics...). If you reporting-lite is succesfull, will it trigger more reporting? Will the solution bare the spot-light of success two years down the road? Maybe puting that SQL Server license to good use and isntall the SSAS makes sense. I says is better to ask forgiveness than to ask permission...

Comment: Setting up an OLAP system is a major undertaking, significantly more involved than just adding a couple of reports to a web site.  Recommending to "just install SSAS" in this case is a bit like recommending to install and learn BizTalk and MSMQ to somebody who asked how to create a simple web service.  Let's not jump the gun here.

Comment: +1. This was going to be my answer, too. Building a cube with Analysis Services for reporting will take some work at first, but it will also open the door to much richer reporting and easier querying in the long run. It also has the potential of offloading your relational system.

Comment: Thankfully the reporting is pretty basic, and is used for public consumption, while more "advanced" stuff is done in Cognos.  So I think I'm going to just get this "reporting-lite" going, and maybe when we get some modern Cognos talk about using web services or something to get that data to the public view...

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, in a situation like this, should I try and tune functions and such so I
>   can always query the data directly for reporting (real-time), or is a better approach to summarize the data I need in a static table via a procedure or saved query, and use that for any reporting?

You can summarize the data in chunks of day, month etc, aggregate these chunks in your reports and invalidate them if some data in the past changes (to correct the errors etc.)

Answer (score 0):

What is your client happy with, in terms of real time reporting & performance?

Having said that, it might be worthwhile to tune your query/indexes.
I'd be surprised if you can't improve performance by modifying your indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Check indexes, rework functions, buy more hardware, do anything before you try the static table route.

Answer (score 0):

100,000 rows per year (presumably around 1 million total) is nothing.  If those queries are taking 5-10 seconds to run then there is either a problem with your query or a problem with your indexes (or both).  I'd put money on your perf issues being the result of one or more table scans or index scans.

When you start to close on the billion-row mark, that's when you often need to start denormalizing, and only in a heavy transactional environment where you can't afford to index more aggressively.

There are, of course, always exceptions, but when you're working with databases it's preferable to look for major optimizations before you start complicating your architecture and schema with partitions and triggers and so on.